# Auto_Prepend_File for non-PHP files?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I asked this question in a different form. Now that the problem is clearer, I'm adding it in this form:

would like to run an auto_prepend_file script (or some equivalent) for binary files (mp3).

If I try to use an Addhandler to treat the mp3 as php, will get all kinds of errors since php will try to parse the mp3 file.

Is there some equivalent way to run an auto_prepend_file for binary files?

(I cannot use mod_rewrite)

Comment: "I cannot use mod_rewrite" - that's a shame, this would be the obvious solution to your problem. Can you explain, what your prepended file does? Maybe there is a third way then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `.htaccess`, you could simply force the prepend file for any kind of request:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "prepend.php"
```

And then in the `prepend.php` check what was requested and either do something (if it is mp3 for example) or not (for any other kind of files)

**Update:**

OK, for non-PHP files it does not work automatically, but you can do following trick (though its not that nice solution):

In `.hatccess` force your `mp3` file to be treated as `PHP`:

```
AddHandler php5-script .mp3
php_value auto_prepend_file "prepend.php"
```

And then in `prepend.php`:

```
// your custom logic here...

header(/* your headers here */);
readfile($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']); // serve the requested file
exit(0);
```

In this way it should work (tested with a PNG file)

Comment: yes. but i need to run the prepend.php even if the http request is for non-php such as mp3

Comment: thank you but need to do this without readfile. People need a direct link. If I serve my own headers, get all sorts of complaints. I tried all combinations of the "Correct headers" but still get complaints. only time it works is if there is a direct link

Comment: well check what headers you get when you download directly and then do the same with PHP - if you choose headers 1:1 what you get downloading directly - no difference should noticed.